# MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus

Tags: ios, swift

Мое приложение вылетает на этой линии: `command.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPrevChapter))` с ошибкой:

> Unsupported action method signature. Must return
>   MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus or take a completion handler as the
>   second argument.

Как это исправить?

код:

```
func registerCommandsIfNeeded() {

        guard !registeredCommands else { return }

        let command = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        command.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        command.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPrevChapter))
        command.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        command.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playNextChapter))
        command.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        command.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pause))
        command.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        command.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play))
        command.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        command.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(togglePlay))

        registeredCommands = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и написано в тексте вылетающей ошибки, метод `playPrevChapter` имеет неправильную сигнатуру. Нужно, чтобы он либо возвращал MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus, или принимал вторым аргументом замыкание с обработчиком ошибки (сигнатуру обработчика можно посмотреть в объявлении метода `addTarget(handler:)`, который принимает замыкание)

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема. Я использовал этот фикс - https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReaderKit/pull/384/commits/483de6dbfbdae8374e36dd0b482c598aba8e4699 для проблемы. Но ошибка не исчезает. Даже если я закомментирую весь класс. Вылетает все равно на той строчке, даже закомментированной. В чем может быть проблема?